# How to INDEX and MATCH with 4 Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm using 4  criteria to determine the retail price and SKU (secondary concern).
I've previously had success when using INDEX and MATCH for 2 criteria. With 4 criteria I'm running into errors

[image: Pricelist]

I've attempted to use this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(index(CFanPriceList,match(1,(A18=CFanStyle)*(B18=CFanColour),*(C18=CFanSize),*(D18=CFanLight),0),7))
```

The Named Ranges are:

```
CFanPrices  A2:H15 

CFanStyle   A2:A15 

CFanColour  B2:B15 

CFanSize    C2:C15 

CFanLight   D2:D15
```

So,  in the example:

```
Fanco Eco Silent,   White,  48',    TRUE
```

I'd expect to return the figure $279

Instead, I get

> **ERROR!** formula parse error

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you can share the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of your formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A18&B18&C18&D18, 
 {A1:A16&B1:B16&C1:C16&D1:D16, A1:G16}, 8, 0)))
```

or with your named ranges:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A18&B18&C18&D18, 
 {CFanStyle&CFanColour&CFanSize&CFanLight, CFanPrices}, 8, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks, legend. Works a treat!